# How to jump between patterns when using :vimgrep (Quickfix list)?

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I am new to vim, and still exploring some features of it. I have a problem with vimgrep. I can search for a pattern like this `vimgrep /define/ **` so that it finds and opens next file that contains a `define`. But I couldn't yet find out how to go to the next file/line that matches my pattern. Any pointers?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Useful commands for the quickfix list (brackets around omittable part of the commands):

- `:cn[ext]` and `:cp[revious]` jump to next and previous entry
- **`:cnf[ile]` and `:cpf[ile]` jump to next and previous file** (if the quickfix list is not sorted by file you could [write a function that `getqflist()`, performs a sort and then `setqflist()`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_sort_Quickfix_list)
- `:cr[ewind]` and `:cla[st]` go to beginning or end of the quickfix list
- `:col[der]` and `:cnew[er]` will iterate through historical quickfix lists.

Needless to say there are plenty of other commands and you can discover them at `:help quickfix`.

Personally I have the following maps :

```
      | ø      | SHIFT   | CTRL
------+--------+---------+---------
<F11> | :cprev | :cpfile | :colder
<F12> | :cnext | :cnfile | :cnewer
```

Of course if you use the location list instead of the quickfix list (`:lvimgrep`) the same commands exist, just replace the initial `c` with an `l` and that's it.

**Vim 8 Additions**:

- `:cdo` : perform a command on all entries of quickfix list. For example
  `:vim /foo/ *.cpp *.h *.hpp` can be followed by
  `:cdo s/pattern/replacement/g`
- `:cfdo`: perform a command an all files in quickfix list. For example,
  `:vim /foo/ *.cpp *.h *.hpp` can be followed by
  `:cfdo %s/2ndpattern/2ndreplacement/g`

Comment: The popular [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) plugin maps `:cprev` and `:cnext` to `[q` and `]q`. Takes very little getting used to.

Comment: It also maps `[<C-q>` and `]<C-q>` to `:cpfile` and `:cnfile`.

Comment: N.B. This is not to be confused with `:cNext` which is what comes up first for me if I type `:cn` and then hit tab. The problem being that you just get a 'No more items' error, because as @RandyMorris' answer points out `:cNext` goes in reverse. I just assumed something was wrong.

Comment: What is the meaning of :c?

Answer (score 10):

To jump to the next occurrence of the patter you can use `:cnext`.  You can go in reverse with `:cNext`.

I'm not sure of a way to skip all occurrences until the next file automatically, but you could open the quickfix window with `:cwindow` to see a list of matches and navigate to those matches by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the entry in the list.

Comment: `:cnfile` is what you want!

Comment: @Benoit: put that in its own answer

Comment: @Benoit,indeed.  I'll let you post that and reap the rewards.